# How to get the props value and use in lifehooks cycle of Vue JS

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm searching a way to get the `props` value through some lifehooks like `mounted` or `updated` and trying to save the value with my `v-model` with some string. But I can't get it.

Though I tried `:value` on the input element with the `props` value and some string and I was able to get it, but it seems like I can't access it without `v-model`, as I researched `v-model` and `:value` can't be together.

The purpose is to get the `value`(with from props and some string) of a `input` tags.

**Parent Component**

```
<invite :user_token="user_token"/>
```

**Child Component**

```
export default {
    props: ['user_token'],

    data() {
        return {
            link: ''
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        console.log(this.user_token);
        this.link = `"http://localhost/johndoe-vue/public/#/invite${this.user_token}"`;
    },
    updated() {
        console.log(this.user_token);
        this.link = `"http://localhost/johndoe-vue/public/#/invite${this.user_token}"`;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Where does `v-model` come into this? Do your `console.log()` calls not work as expected? You don't appear to be doing anything with `link` either

Comment: My link is coming from child component. `<input type="text" v-model="link"  class="form-control">`. While the `console.log()` yes it's not working I can't display the `props` user token on that `console.log()`

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO Nigel!

Are you looking for something like this, perhaps?

**ParentComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <invite :userToken="userToken"></invite>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
import Invite from "@/Invite.vue";
export default {
    components: {
        Invite
    },
    data() {
        return {
            userToken: "fooBar",
        };
    }
}
</script>
```

**ChildComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <p v-if="inviteLink != ''">{{ inviteLink }}</p>
    </div>
</template>
export default {
    props: {
        userToken: {
            type: String,
        }
    },

    data() {
        return {
            inviteLink: ""
        }
    },

    created() {
        if(this.userToken != "") {
            this.inviteLink == "/your-link-here/"+this.userToken;
        }
    }

}
```

Also, you should check out the [Vue.js Style Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/). They've marked multi-word component names as essential. Your `Invite` component should be renamed to `BaseInvite` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Have  you tried to `$emit` *this.link*

Comment: No, I was passing the user token from my parent component to my child component and, that user token will be used in my child component.

Comment: Ok I see... Add the `user_token` to the ```data:(){ return: { link: '', user_token: '' }}

Comment: Noted, let me try this, that `user_token` from props will I save it to my new variable in `data() {}`?

Comment: Yes exactly. The point is initialise it first

Comment: I did what you said above. I tried. `token: this.user_token` then I call it on my html and it looks like the `token` is empty and can't get the `user_token`.

Answer (score 0):

Props is accessible through the `$props` property of your component. You would reference it like: `this.$props.[property name]`. `$props` is called an instance property; there are many of them and they are each accessible this way. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Instance-Properties

Keep in mind that the Vue life cycle methods are somewhat inconsistent. Which instance properties are accessible depends on the method (ie: you can't reference `$el` in `created(...)`.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Comment: I tried adding the `$props` but still I can't save it on my `v-model` `link`.

Comment: Are you trying to add a v-model to a component? You will need to explicitly write out what v-model does on the component that will be modifying the data. The docs has an example. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

Comment: Either way, referencing props like `this.[property name]` will not work; you have to first reference the instance property with `this.$props.[prop name]`. You can even do this inside a component's template like `<span> User Token: {{ $props.user_token }} </span>`.

Comment: Yes it's working on displaying it in the template. However, what if I would like to reference  some dummy link + `user_token` in my `v-model` `link`. So that when I see the `<input>` on my browser it has the value of what I referenced in my `v-model ` `link`.

Comment: It sounds like you don't really need a v-model but rather a watcher or computed value. v-model is usually used for two way binding which doesn't seem like what you're doing (I could be misunderstanding).

Comment: Hmm let me try that, that's why I'm doing that because the `v-model` that has a dummy link with `user_token` is because it will be use in copying to clipboard.